# How to pass request parameter values for Grails params.list to read them in as array instead of string?

Tags: grails

I have the following code in my Grails controller...

```
def teams = params.list('team')
```

And in the post being submitted I see in Chrome dev tools network tab...

```
team:Yankees mets
```

Two values separated by a space. On the server side this is read as a string, how can I pass the data in so it is read as an array (with "Yankees" being the first element and "mets" the second)?

I tried separating the values by comma instead but that didn't work either.

Comment: Or is it the case that params.list will only be a list when there is more than parameter with the same name?

Comment: Could you clarify your use case? I couldn't figure out what you are attempting to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to understand what `params.list()` expects you to submit to it and how that differs from other ways of sending in array like data.

`params.list()` expects that you submit the same parameter multiple times either via `GET` or `POST` an example of such a form would be:

```
...
<input type="text" name="team" value="One" />
<input type="text" name="team" value="Two" />
...
```

Which would result in the following being posted as form data:

```
team=One
team=Two
```

The above example as a querystring (used in a `GET`) would look like:

```
?team=One&team=Two
```

As you can see from the above `params.list()` expects you to submit your data in a very specific way so it understands how to parse it into a collection (e.g. `list`).

If, however, you wish to use a single field and separate your data using some token (such as a comma) you could parse the value of the single parameter into a list using either `tokenize()` or `split()`. For example:

List teams = `params?.team?.tokenize(',')`

You'll have to be careful about handling empty/null values. Also the above example expects that `param.team` is going to be a `String` (important to note if your are sending a comma separated list of numeric values and only one value is present).